# NginX скрывает IP клиента от Python сервера

Tags: сервер, nginx, веб-сервер, ip, localhost

У меня есть рабочая конфигурация **NginX**, и казалось бы в ней всё хорошо, но я заметил, что скрываемый веб-сервер на **Python** не видит **IP** клиентов, NginX при пересылки ставит свой IP `127.0.0.1`, что совсем не желанный результат. Я пробовал гуглить вопрос, комментировать части команд, но безуспешно... Как это исправить?

Мой код:

```
proxy_read_timeout 950s;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;

    server_name_in_redirect off;

    ssl_certificate ...../ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key ...../ca.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/forwarded/

Comment: @defrag спасибо! Как я понял, заменить IP `127.0.0.1` NginX не позволит, но можно на Питоне брать настоящий IP из дополнительного header'a.

Comment: [какой редкий вопрос!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=nginx+127.0.0.1)